# Swift 5 - iOS14 - customize UIDatePicker

Tags: swift, uidatepicker, ios14

I try to customize the UIDatePicker in iOS14 but I'm unfortunately unable to do this. I want to change the background and border color of the UIDatePicker.

Here is my code in my class:

```
fileprivate let picker: UIDatePicker = {
        let picker = UIDatePicker()
        picker.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        picker.datePickerMode = .time
        picker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .inline
        picker.layer.borderWidth = 0
        picker.minuteInterval = 15
        picker.backgroundColor = .clear
        picker.overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
        return picker
    }()
```

I want to change the background color of the inner gray part of the UIDatePicker to white or in this example to clear.

[image]

As you can see, the gray part on the white background doesn't really look good.

On note: I use the UIDatePicker in a UITableViewCell.

I hope you guys can help me and maybe there is only 1 or 2 lines which are missing in my code. :)

Best regards and stay healthy!
Roman

Answer (score 0):

UIDatePicker is not really customizable.

Known workaround is to place a UILabel on top the picker and format the label how you want and update it for UIDatePicker's value changes

Comment: Thank you for your answer. :) But ... damn apple ... I thought that a least the font color ist customizable